# More than one hit in a json string

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I have made a function that fetches data from a service and adds it to my Application. The problem is when I get more than 1 hit per "duplicates", everything stops. This means if I get the result of the following string below, I'm not able to fetch the data correctly:

```
{
"qry":"Programming service",
"result":{
"hitLinesBeforeFilter":1,
"approxHits":1,
"userID":299228,
"1":{"listing":{
"table":"listing",
"id":"693144",
"duplicates":
[
{
"table":"listing",
"id":"693144:0",
"idlinje":"D1E6C4B001",
"tlfnr":"99886644",
"etternavn":"Programming Service AS",
"veinavn":"Kolåsveien",
"husnr":"11",
"postnr":"1234",
"virkkode":"N",
"apparattype":"M",
"telco":"MF",
"kilde":"D",
"foretaksnr":"123456789",
"bransjekode":"19940",
"prioritet":"0",
"kommunenr":"1234",
"poststed":"Bergen",
"kommune":"Bergen",
"fylke":"Hordaland",
"landsdel":"V",
"bransjebokmaal":"Programming and software",
"bransjenynorsk":"Programming and software"
},
**{
"table":"listing",
"id":"693144:1",
"idlinje":"D1E6C4B000",
"bransjekode":"46955",
"bransjebokmaal":"hardware",
"bransjenynorsk":"hardware"
}**
]
}
},
"dummy":null
}
}
```

My problem is that whenever the last part  (in strong/**) are added in the return, it doesn't work.

The rest of my code is as follows:

```
Class Result
        Property listing As Listing
    End Class

Class Listing
        Property table As String
        Property id As String
        Property idlinje As String
        Property duplicates As Duplicate()
    End Class

Class Duplicate
        Property table As String
        Property id As String
        Property idlinje As String
        Property tlfnr As String
        Property etternavn As String
        Property fornavn As String
        Property veinavn As String
        Property husnr As String
        Property postnr As String
        Property virkkode As String
        Property apparattype As String
        Property telco As String
        Property kilde As String
        Property bkdata As String
        Property prioritet As String
        Property fodselsdato As String
        Property kommunenr As String
        Property poststed As String
        Property kommune As String
        Property fylke As String
        Property landsdel As String
        Property foretaksnr As String
    End Class

Public Sub findContact()
        lblContactResults.Visible = True
        Dim contactLink As String
        Dim phone As String = newCustSearch.Text
        Dim url As String = "My string on web to get the json data"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim json As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Dim results = o("result")

        For Each resultProperty In results.Value(Of JObject)()
            'Only get properties like "1" inside the root "result" property
            If Not Integer.TryParse(resultProperty.Key, Nothing) Then Continue For
            'Approach 1: Manually Iterate over the duplicates array inside each result
            'Dim duplicatesArray = resultProperty.Value("listing")("duplicates").Value(Of JArray)()
            'For Each duplicate In duplicatesArray
            'Make sure there is a fornavn property
            'If Duplicate("fornavn") Is Nothing Then Continue For
            ' Console.WriteLine(Duplicate("fornavn"))
            'Next

            'Approach 2: Deserialize the listing into a .Net object
            Dim serializer As JsonSerializer = New JsonSerializer()
            Dim resultObject As Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Result)(resultProperty.Value.ToString())

            For Each duplicateObject In resultObject.listing.duplicates
                Dim firstName As String = ""
                Dim middleName As String = ""
                If duplicateObject.fornavn <> "" And duplicateObject.fornavn.Contains(" ") Then
                    Dim name As String() = duplicateObject.fornavn.Split(" ")
                    firstName = name(0)
                    middleName = name(1)
                Else
                    firstName = duplicateObject.fornavn
                End If

                contactLink = "<a href='#" + i.ToString + "'class='customerEniro' onClick='test()' data-contact-Firstname='" + firstName + "' data-contact-Middlename='" + middleName + "' data-contact-Lastname='" + duplicateObject.etternavn + "' data-contact-phone='" + duplicateObject.tlfnr + "'data-contact-born='" + Convert.ToDateTime(duplicateObject.fodselsdato).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "' data-contact-address='" + duplicateObject.veinavn + " " + duplicateObject.husnr + "'data-contact-addresszip='" + duplicateObject.postnr + "'data-contact-addressplace='" + duplicateObject.poststed + "'data-contact-eniro='" + duplicateObject.idlinje + "' > "
                contactLink += i.ToString + " - " + duplicateObject.fornavn + " " + duplicateObject.etternavn + " - " + duplicateObject.tlfnr + " - " + duplicateObject.veinavn + " " + duplicateObject.husnr + " - " + duplicateObject.postnr + " " + duplicateObject.poststed
                contactLink += "</a>" + vbNewLine
                lblContactResults.Text += contactLink
                i += 1
            Next
        Next
        btnSaveNewCustomer.Visible = True

        If lblContactResults.Text = "" Then
            lblContactResults.Text = "No hits. Try again!"
            lblMsg.Text = "No one was found."
        End If
        updatePanel2.Update()
    End Sub
```

Can anyone see any obvious reasons why the code is failing? I think there is something With the duplicates and more than one hit, that I can't handle.

Comment: Show the code where you actually dserialize it.  And expand on "didnt work" - thats a bit vague

Comment: I am getting a different error... It's due to fornavn being null and you are performing .Contains on null.  See: `If duplicateObject.fornavn <> "" And duplicateObject.fornavn.Contains(" ") Then`  Changing it to `If  Not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(duplicateObject.fornavn) AndAlso duplicateObject.fornavn.Contains(" ") Then` prevent the condition from triggering error...  see https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2DE1l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this line: `If duplicateObject.fornavn <> "" And duplicateObject.fornavn.Contains(" ") Then` is the culprit.  The multiple duplicate is fine.  If you see the json, fornavn is not in there, therefore during deserialization, fornvavn will remain null.  doing `.Contain(...)` on null cause issue.

Change it to string null check and chain it with `AndAlso` to short circuit the and operator like so:

`If  Not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(duplicateObject.fornavn) AndAlso duplicateObject.fornavn.Contains(" ") Then`

Working example at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2DE1l

Comment: It worked like a charm! :) Thank you very much for Your response in this question.